# MySQL Query to find titles of movies with actors that have their name starting with B

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a MySQL Query which would find the titles of movies led by actors that have their names starting with B. I have got 2 tables, an Actor Table and Movie Table. In my Actor table, I've got the actID and actName, and in my Movie table, I've got the mvID, actID (FK), mvTitle, mvGenre, mvPrice, mvYear. I have already written a query for a similiar problem and I have tried to modify it for this query but it isn't exactly working. What I have so far is:

```
SELECT mvTitle
FROM Movie
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mvGenre
              FROM Movie,
                   Actor
              WHERE (Actor.actID = Movie.actID)
                and (Actor.actName LIKE 'B%'))
```

Which returns all of the movie titles rather than returning the specific ones (as it should only return 3 titles) but returns all of the 10 titles.

Comment: You need a correlated sub-query. (I.e. with a condition including the main query Movie table.)

Comment: because you use EXISTS, use inner join

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `EXISTS` asks whether the sub query returns a row or not. Your sub query returns all 'B%' actors with their movies. Always. You can check this by running the sub query alone. Its result has nothing to do with the movie of the main query you want information for. This is called a non-correlated sub query. You want a correlated sub query instead, where you are not looking up all 'B%' actors for all movies, but 'B%' actors for the one movie of the row in the main query. See fa06's answer for the difference...

Comment: ... Personally, I prefer Udayan's query. An `IN` clause makes this even easier to read. There we use a non-correlated query by the way.

Comment: That's a strange data model by the way. Why does the movie table have an actor ID? That would mean that there is one actor only in each movie. I would rather expect an m:n relation (multiple actors in one movie and one actor can play in various movies). That would ask for a bridge table `movie_actor(movie_id, actor_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT mvTitle
FROM Movie where actID in (select actID from Actor where actName LIKE 'B%')
```

Comment: Subqueries are slow and ugly, you should avoid them everywhere it is possible, in this particular case, for sure.

Comment: @ygorbunkov: You are wrong. You shouldn't make such statements here. The opposite is true: Use `[NOT] IN` and `[NOT] EXISTS` when you merely want to lookup data in another table. Only join, when you are interested in a joined result. Joining here would mean to produce a large intermediate data set that you'd have to reduce with `DISTINCT` then. This can be costly.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.mvTitle from Movie m JOIN Actor a on a.actId = m.actId WHERE a.actName LIKE 'B%'
```

Try that... Instead of a subselect, I've opted to use a join -- it seems cleaner to me.

Comment: I'd do `SELECT DISTINCT`, to avoid duplicates in case a movie has several B actors.

Comment: Joining two tables although you only want to show data from one of them seems cleaner to you? That is strange. You've already been told, that you are missing `DISTINCT`, which comes from producing an intermediate result that contains movies multifold. One aim of SQL is to be read like spoken language. E.g.: "Select the movies for with **exists** an actor with the letter B". Not "select the movies that are combined with their actors with the letter B, but I mean the movies only, and each just once please".

Answer (score 2):

use correlated subquery

```
SELECT mvTitle
FROM Movie a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Actor b
              WHERE a.actID = b.actID
                and b.actName LIKE 'B%')
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you suggest to OP to use joins and avoid subqueries as they are slow and ugly?

Comment: @ygorbunkov: Probably because `EXISTS` is more readable and usually *faster*, because it can stop the lookup at the first match found per movie.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: ok, let's make it '*slower* most of the times, and **ugly** '